# Continuing code after executing a File - Python

Tags: python, user-interface, continue

I have made a Simple GUI that launches when i run my Twitch TV IRC Bot. But, the main bot doesn't continue until after i close the GUI. How would i make it so the Script runs at the same time as the GUI?
This is the GUI:

```
##--GUI--##
def whitelist_wipe():
execfile('command_whitelist_wipe.py')

def modpack():
modpack = modpack_input.get()
return



root = Tk()
modpack_input = StringVar()

root.title('Geekster_Bot')
root.geometry('450x450+500+300')

WhitelistButton = Button(root, text = 'Clear Whitelist!', command + whitelist_wipe).pack()

SubmitButton = Button(root, text = 'Change Modpack', command = modpack).pack()

ModpackName = Entry(root, textvariable=modpack_input).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This is the part where it launches the GUI from the main Bot scrpit:

```
try:
    execfile('GUI.py')

except:
    print('Error loading GUI')
```

How would i continue the code with the GUI open?

EDIT

GUI.py;

```
##--GUI--##
def whitelist_wipe():
    execfile('command_whitelist_wipe.py')

def modpack_var():
    modpack_input = modpack_user.get()



root = Tk()
modpack_user = StringVar()

root.title('Geekster_Bot')
root.geometry('350x100+500+300')

Label1 = Label(root, text = 'Geekster_Bot Controls!').pack()

WhitelistButton = Button(root, text = 'Clear Whitelist!', command =whitelist_wipe).pack(side = LEFT)


SubmitButton = Button(root, text = 'Change Modpack', command = modpack_var).pack()

ModpackName = Entry(root, textvariable=modpack_user).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Main Bot;

```
try:
    #Create thread
    gui_thread = threading.Thread( target = execfile, args = ('GUI.py',) )
    #Start thread
    gui_thread.start()
    #Code to run in the main thread

except:
    print('Error loading GUI')

def message(msg): #function for sending messages to the IRC chat
            global queue
            queue = queue + 1
            print queue
            if queue < 20: #ensures does not send >20 msgs per 30 seconds.
                twitch = ('OUTPUT ON ' + channel + ' :' + msg + '\r\n')
                irc.send('PRIVMSG ' + channel + ' :' + msg + '\r\n')
                print (twitch)
            else:
                print 'Message deleted'

def socialtimer(): #function for announcing social every 3 minutes
            global ntimer
            z = open(r'E:\Geekster_Bot\Twitter.txt')
            SOCIAL = z.read()
            message (SOCIAL)
            print 'Social Timers Started!'
            ntimer = threading.Timer(1200,socialtimer)
            ntimer.start()

def queuetimer(): #function for resetting the queue every 30 seconds
            global queue
            print 'queue reset'
            queue = 0
            threading.Timer(30,queuetimer).start()

def modpack_var():
            modpack_input = modpack_user.get()

##--Main Bot--##

#General variables
newsmsg = 'whitelist'
modpack = modpack_input
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the gui itself runs in a loop it blocks the thread you start it in until you stop the loop (close the gui). You need to start the gui in a different thread from the main one.

You can do this using the threading module:

```
import threading

try:
    #Create thread
    gui_thread = threading.Thread( target = execfile, args = ('GUI.py',) )
    #Start thread
    gui_thread.start()
    #Code to run in the main thread

except:
    print('Error loading GUI')
```

In this code the `gui_thread` object is a thread, which runs the `execfile` callable (a function in this case) with the parameter `'GUI.py'` on start.
Check the threading module documentation for further info: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/threading.html

Comment: That works really well! Opens both! But, i get a error when trying to use the GUI. The first Button works fine. The second one that involves a variable doesn't. When clicked it says: File "GUI.py", line 8, in modpack_var
    modpack_input = modpack_user.get()
NameError: global name 'modpack_user' is not defined

Comment: That seems to be an error in the GUI.py module (if you would run the gui in the main thread you would get the same error). Check if the `modpack_user` variable is in the scope of the call, or it exists at all. NameError exceptions are raised if there is no variable with the name you are trying to use. If you update the original code I could help more.

Comment: In the function `modpack_var` add the line `global modpack_user` before the `get` function call. This tells the interpreter not to handle `modpack_user` as a local variable in the function but as a global, defined at the module level. But be careful if the `modpack_var` function gets called before you actually create the `modpack_user` variable you'll get the same error.